# Sort matrix columns based on the values in the first row

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, matrix

Currently trying to do some beginner matrix handling exercises, but are unsure on how to sort a nxn matrix's column by the columns first index. etc.
[image: Exercise]

It should be a method that could work on any size matrix, as it will not be the same size matrix every time.
Anyone who has any good suggestions?

Comment: Please show us your effort and where do you have specific questions.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Provide your attempt code please.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation here can be very simple depending on how the data, ie. the matrix, is represented. If it is given as a list of column-lists, it just needs a sort. For the given example:

```
>>> m = [[2, 3, 7], [-1, -2, 5.2], [0, 1, 4], [2, 4, 5]]
>>> y = sorted(m, key=lambda x: x[0])
>>> y
[[-1, -2, 5.2], [0, 1, 4], [2, 3, 7], [2, 4, 5]]
```

Other representations might need a more complex approach. For example, if the matrix is given as a list of rows:

```
>>> m = [[2, -1, 0, 2], [3, -2, 1, 4], [7, 5.2, 4, 5]]
>>> order = sorted(range(len(m[0])), key=lambda x: m[0][x])
>>> order
[1, 2, 0, 3]
>>> y = [[row[x] for x in order] for row in m]
>>> y
[[-1, 0, 2, 2], [-2, 1, 3, 4], [5.2, 4, 7, 5]]
```

The idea here is that first, we will get the order the elements are going to be in based on the first row. We can do that by sorting `range(4)`, so `[0, 1, 2, 3]` with the sorting key (the value used for sorting) being the i-th value of the first row.

The result is that we get `[1, 2, 0, 3]` which says: Column index 1 is first, then index 2, 0 and finally 3.

Now we want to create a new matrix where every row follows that order which we can do with a list comprehension over the original matrix, where for each row, we create a new list that has the elements of the row according to the order we determined before.

Note that this approach creates new lists for the whole matrix - if you're dealing with large matrices, you probably want to use the appropriate primitives from numpy and swap the elements around in place.

Comment: hmm alright, my data is represented as the rows are the vektor which are then horisontally stacked `[[ 2.  -1.   0.   2. ]
 [ 3.  -2.   1.   4. ]
 [ 7.   5.2  4.   5. ]]`  I've tried reshaping them by np.reshape to get it to be presented as yours, but couldt find any good solutions for that. for example like this `k=np.reshape(X,[len(X[:,0]),len(X[0,:])])` .  I've also tried dividing them up by using for loops, but as my skills are very limited, and the size of the matrix is unknown im unsure how do it.

Comment: @Brokhus I extended the answer to cover that case as well.

Answer (score 0):

If `matrix` is your input, you can do:

```
result = list(zip(*sorted(zip(*matrix))))
```

So working from inside out, this expression does:

- `zip`: to iterate the transposed of the matrix (rows become columns and vice versa)
- `sorted`: sorts the transposed matrix. No need to provide a custom key, the sorting will be by the first element (row, which is a column in the original matrix). If there is a tie, by second element (row), ...etc.
- `zip`: to iterate the transposed of the transposed matrix, i.e. transposing it back to its original shape
- `list` to turn the iterable to a list (a matrix)